# C++ Vector Subscript out of range with opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I have problems regarding vector subscript out of range.Eyes[0] refers to left eye while eyes[1] refer to right eye.The function of the code below allows an OpenCV function called eyecascade to track eyes and I have edited it to output the coordinates of the eyes,however for the right eye of eyes[1],I believe it causes the vector to be out of range.

```
vector<Rect> eyes;
        eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes);
        unsigned int x = eyes.size();
        {
            Point eye_center(eyes[0].x + eyes[0].width / 2,  eyes[0].y + eyes[0].height / 2);
            int radius = cvRound((eyes[0].width + eyes[0].height)*0.25);
            circle(frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5);
            printf("eyes0_x;%d", eyes[0].x);
            printf(" eyes0_y;%d\n",eyes[0].y );
            circle(frame, eye_center, radius, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 5);
            printf("eyes1_x;%d", eyes[(1)].x);
            printf(" eyes1_y;%d\n", eyes[(1)].y);
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Check number of vector elements.

Comment: How do you initialize `eyes`? What does `eyeCascade.detectMultiScale(faceROI, eyes)` do? Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve].

Comment: ok i have edited it

Comment: Just a guess but you are calling your eyes1_x different than eyes0_x. Shouldn't you use `eyes[1].x` instead of `eyes[(1)].x`? Nonetheless, this is still no [mcve].